# Pass onclick action from parent to child react

Tags: reactjs

I have a button in the parent component and I want to pass that click action to the child component, when I click the button I want to use that click to get data from backend,
the point is just to pass click action or function to child

```
const parent = ()=>{
return (
<>
<button onclick={handlcklick}>Click me</Button>
</>
)

}
```

use that handlclick in child

```
const child = ()=>{
const handlclick =(e)=>{
alert("hello")
}
return (
<>
</>
)

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no dependency on the parent component better to use that function inside the child component to avoid more props drilling.

Comment: i cant because childe i use it like header where i get query by input and the other button is in body and I want to use that to get that query